# Vim filetype plugin executed twice when enter in insert mode?

Tags: vim, ftplugin

I am editing a file of `filetype=help` and want to do something when entering in insert mode. So I put a new ftplugin in `~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim`:

```
" ~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim
echom 'execute help ftplugin'
augroup filetype_help
    autocmd! " or autocmd! InsertEnter <buffer>
    autocmd InsertEnter <buffer> echom 'enter insert mode'
augroup END
```

But it doesn't work when I firstly enter in insert mode. I also find that it will execute the plugin code in `~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim` when firstly entering in insert mode, which will show `execute help ftplugin` twice.

Maybe it only appears in some vim versions, and my system environment is:

- vim: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10) containing patches: 1-207, 209-326.
- system: openSuse 42.3

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Do you have any plugin that may interfere here? I'd try to open a help file after `:set verbose=20` and check the (long) output for what exactly happens.

Comment: @IngoKarkat maybe it is related to vim versions, could you tell me your vim version?

Comment: Neither on Vim 7.4.1689 nor on 8.1.744 on Ubuntu. Backward compatibility is great, I doubt it's related to that. Rather caused by configuration.

Comment: Maybe check you autocmds with `:autocmd InsertEnter`.